# Using "class" in <html> tag - necessary or not?

Tags: html, css, kindle

Publishing an ebook, and the Kindle validation (in *Kindle Previewer 3*) fails because the conversion software adds a "class" attribute to the `<html>` tag.

The style only sets margins and padding to 0, which surely could be as easily done by redefining the html tag.

a) would it be safe to remove the attribute, and b) was it even necessary in the first place?

(I realise the answer should be very simple to find, but searching Google for the terms html, class, tag etc is only ever going to give me generic pages on writing html or CSS :(

`<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="calibre">`

where `.calibre { margin:0; padding:0;}`

I would prefer `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`

where html `{ margin:0; padding:0;}`

Comment: There is no harm in having a class on `<html>` tag. And especially with the usage of frameworks, it is common practice.

Comment: “ a) would it be safe to remove the attribute” — Have you tried?

Comment: “b) was it even necessary in the first place?” — Depends on context

Comment: @tacoshy, I realise it's not normally a problem, and html does allow for it, BUT, the specific situation makes it undesirable i.e. Amazon will not accept the book to publish with what it sees as errors.

Comment: @Quentin, I have removed it, and it compiles the ebook without issue. The draft is accepted by Kindle Previewer. I was really just worried about it affecting the layout when published, and I get the impression from the answers that I can pretty much either leave it out, or shift the attributes to the html tag.

Answer (score -3):

try to use class attribute in body tag it work similar

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanks, but I was trying to avoid unnecessary "class" attributes when I know how touchy the validator can be!